# ignoring the build folder in an eclipse project in git repo

Tags: eclipse, git

I am using eclipse java as an editor and would like to use the .gitignore to exclude the build folder for the project. This is what I have currently written in my .gitignore. The syntax seems to be right; I used the git documentation but I may have interpreted it wrong.

```
#ignoring the files within the build folder
/build/
build/**
```

I'm using a brand new repo so I shouldn't have any problems with already logged files in the repo.

I am trying to get git to ignore the build folder in the project file using a .gitignore. The ignore file didn't work. What could be a solution?

Comment: So what is the problem you're having and trying to solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: This isn't about removing an already tracked file, this is about an initial git ignore

Comment: If the file `.gitignore` is located in the folder that contains the subfolder `build`, both (`/build/` and `build/**`) should work. If `build` is not empty, you can also right-click the `build` folder and choose _Team > Ignore_ to create the `.gitignore` file (if it does not yet exist) and add the line `/build/`.

Comment: Right click where?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way the .gitignore is written, this file needs to be in the same subfolder as the build folder, the file being ignored.